# Failed to create and edit tables in Supabase, "Failed to create pg.columns:..."

Tags: postgresql, supabase, vault, supabase-database

I have failed to create or edit tables in Supabase. It is showing an error message "Failed to create pg.columns: must be the owner of event trigger pgsodium_trg_mask_update". I think it has something to do with the launch of supabase vault, but I don't have the vault feature on my settings dashboard for now.

I am using supabase's free tier.

[image]

I have tried deleting the vault and pgsodium triggers since these are new but still failed to create the tables. I have even failed to remove the pgsodium extension. I am looking for a way to create the secret keys or disable this feature and have supabase working as before and I should be able to create tables.

Comment: Hmm, would you mind contacting support about this issue? https://app.supabase.com/support/new

Comment: Seeing this as well when trying to migrate from a MySQL database to Supabase using [nmig](https://github.com/AnatolyUss/nmig)

Comment: Having the same error when trying to use `ALTER TABLE` to add a foreign key.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have not found a solution yet for the table editor but I am using the SQL editor. The tables can be created and edited successfully from there.